# TextRendering in panel only works when it's behind a label

Tags: c#, vb.net, graphics, paintevent

I'm using TextRenderingHint.AntiAliasGridFit to render my text, because my text looks very bad when I don't.

But for some strange reason the text only renders fine when its behind a label (transparant back color).

So I paint the text in a panel and there's a label with the same width as the panel inside it. When the text I paint is behind the label it looks good, else it looks the same as before. Any idea's why?

```
Private Sub Form1_Paint(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs) Handles pnlPanel.Paint

    Dim big_font As New Font("Times New Roman", 60, FontStyle.Bold, GraphicsUnit.Pixel)    
    e.Graphics.TextRenderingHint = TextRenderingHint.AntiAliasGridFit
    e.Graphics.DrawString("Text", big_font, Brushes.Black, 10, 80)

End Sub
```

Please tell me if there are better ways to get a smoother text.

Thanks

Comment: show your screen shot?

Comment: http://i39.tinypic.com/sv77uu.jpg --> With label above
http://i39.tinypic.com/30rqmoy.jpg --> With label visibility set to false

Comment: Can't reproduce your problem, I don't need any `Label`, just with your code, the text is rendered smoothly.

Comment: Have you tried it inside a panel? Seems to only work in my case when there's a control over it :s.

Comment: I painted it directly on the form, you mean you painted it on a `panel`? but your code shows that you painted it on a form.

Comment: Also tried painted it on a panel and it didn't show any difference.

Comment: Handles pnlPanel.Paint, pnlPanel = panel

Comment: yes, I also tried painting on a panel as I said before. There is only a difference here is **I used C#** to test, not **VB.NET**, but I don't think it matters because of the same environment `CLR` with the same framework.

Comment: hmm, I tried to Paint in different panels and I always get the same problem. Weird :S